# thymeleaf not able to parse the expression

Tags: jsp, thymeleaf

Thyme-leaf is not able to parse the above expression, not sure. Is something wrong in above expression?

I have tries diff combination of same expression but nothing seems to work.

```html
<label class="form-label" for="general_details" 
  th:text="${detsils.date.newDate==null ? #{text from message.properties} : #{text from message.properties}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `detsils` is a valid model, the proper syntax is:

```html
<label class="form-label" for="general_details" 
  th:text="${detsils.date.newDate==null} ? 
  #{text from message.properties} : #{text from message.properties}">
```

**Thymeleaf** documentation on [Conditional expressions](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#conditional-expressions) and [Default expressions (Elvis operator)](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#default-expressions-elvis-operator) and a [Conditionals in Thymeleaf](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-conditionals) tutorial.

Comment: I tried this, still the same error cannot parse. Can we write conditions in this type of tags?

Comment: Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Could not parse as expression:

Comment: @AdityaGupta Please copy and paste here the complete exception message.

Comment: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [*********8.html]")
        at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241)
        at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)

Comment: @AdityaGupta Try with something as simple as `th:text="'Foo'"`, then with `th:text="${true} ? 'True' : 'False'"` and finally with actual expressions added one by one.

Comment: Actually th:text="${detsils.date.newDate==null , actually date object is not found by thymeleaf while parsing. But its there in data object

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'date' cannot be found on null

Comment: @AdityaGupta The error message implies that the `detsils` model is either null or not present. Update your post with the code of the controller method that uses this template.